# user authentication situation while launching asp.net website using godaddy

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, authentication, web

I am new with asp.net and web hosting. I built website on visual studio2010-3.5 framwork. To authenticate user I went into asp.net configuration where I created 3 users and 3 roles. Each user is assigned to a role. .NET framework created a data called ASPNETDB.mdf which contains users and roles. The user authentication is working fine on local machine. My web hosting provider is godaddy.com.
Now, the problem is where to upload ASPNETDB.mdf database (in godaddy.com ) so user authentication start working as it is working on my local machine. Or is there another way to handle this situation. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Feel free to ask if more information is needed.
Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I had gone through link given by user @Justcuz before his post. I am learning from the following site. [Link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1657285.aspx/1?Club+Web+site+login+problem)

Answer (score -1):

You can set up user authentication and permissions on go-daddy itself.  You go under the web hosting and FTP manager and choose permissions and uncheck read. By disabling ‘Read’ access, the directory will become password protected online.

Here is the link to go-daddy's support page on the topic. http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/3977/password-protecting-web-directories-on-a-windows-hosting-account

Comment: In this way any user will be able to see my information and there will be only login and password for all users. I have several users. I want to assign these users to role (there are three roles). on the basis of roles they belong to they can access web pages and other resource of website.

Comment: irrelevant answer